# Hot code replace failed - hierarchy change not implemented" on @Entity classes

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, jvm, java

Getting this specific error message

"Hot code replace failed - hierarchy change not implemented"

When trying to change an existing *method body*.

Normally changing method bodies works - but regularly breaks on method bodies in JPA `@Entity` classes.  Any idea what's wrong?

Environment: Glassfish 3.1.2.2, Eclipse Juno, JDK 1.6

No difference with DCEVM

Comment: Most probably what's happening is that the instance you currently have while modifying the code is a JPA proxy, which is created on the fly and subClasses your original `@Entity` class. This is just a guess though from the error you are stating and relating that it happens with `@Entity` classes